# powershell add-member cmdlet issue

Tags: powershell

I'm playing with the add-member cmdlet and found the following three piece of code does not give me the same result. Any anyone explain why? Thanks.

```
################################################################ 
$hash = @{"a" = "aa"; "b" = "bb"}
$result = new-object psobject
$result | Add-Member $hash
$result

################################################################ 
$hash = @{"a" = "aa"; "b" = "bb"}
$result = new-object psobject | Add-Member $hash
$result

################################################################ 
$hash = @{"a" = "aa"; "b" = "bb"}
$result = (new-object psobject | Add-Member $hash)
$result
```

Comment: On powershell v2 all gives error. In v3 last 2 have same behaviour (no value in `$result` ) and they make no sense for me ;)  Personally  I use `$result = new-object psobject -Property $hash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st one works because $result psobject creation is performed before the Add-Member. The second 2 do not work because $result is null.  Code below ensures the order of statement evaluation.

```
################################################################ 
$hash = @{"a" = "aa"; "b" = "bb"}
($result = new-object psobject) | Add-Member $hash
$result
```

Answer (score 2):

$hash is probably binding to the wrong parameter. The correct way would be to decide on the member type (NoteProperty in this example), a Name and value:

```
$result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MyHash -Value $hash
```

If you assign the result to a variable add the -PassThru switch:

```
$result = new-object psobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MyHash -Value $hash -PassThru
$result.MyHash
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using $hash as a positional parameter for Add-Member. If you look at the help for Add-Member, in PowerShell v2, the first parameter is MemberType. So your first example is equivalent to

```
$result | Add-Member -MemberType @{"a" = "aa"; "b" = "bb"}
```

PowerShell can't interpret your hash table as the MemberType, so it gives an error. This applies to all three examples.

In PowerShell v3, it interprets your first example as

```
$result | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{"a" = "aa"; "b" = "bb"}
```

As others have already pointed out, you need to use the -PassThru parameter if you are assigning a result with Add-member.

Answer (score 1):

`Add-Member` doesn't return anything unless you use the `-PassThru` argument.